# Eclipse thinks __cplusplus is defined for a .c file

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

I am using Eclipse Juno with thew ADT for an Android NDK based project and I have found that the Eclipse indexer thinks __cplusplus is defined inside a .C file.

I have to #undef __cplusplus in order for the file to display correctly without any non-existant errors being found but everything builds OK without this expedient.

How can I tell the indexer that __cplusplus should not be defined for my .c file ?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you sure that it's not, either directly or indirectly through inclusion?

Comment: My C source file does not include any files that define __cplusplus.  AIUI this defined by the compiler which builds my code fine, it is only the Eclipse indexer which has problems as I said in my post.